# Open and closed subgroups of continous functions with max metric

Tags: metric-spaces

Looking at the metric space C[-1,1] with the max metric.

Show that only one of the following subgroups is open.
How many of them are closed?

$A = \{f \in C[-1,1] : f(x)<1 \,\,\,\forall x \in [-1,0);\, f(x)<0 \,\,\, \forall x \in [0,1]\}$
$B = \{f \in C[-1,1] : f(x)<1 \,\,\,\forall x \in [-1,0];\, f(x)<0 \,\,\, \forall x \in (0,1]\}$
$C = \{f \in C[-1,1] : f(x) \leq 1 \,\,\,\forall x \in [-1,0);\, f(x) \leq 0 \,\,\, \forall x \in [0,1]\}$
$D = \{f \in C[-1,1] : f(x) \leq 1 \,\,\,\forall x \in [-1,0];\, f(x) \leq 0 \,\,\, \forall x \in (0,1]\}$

I think $A,B$ are not closed because the sequence $f_n(x)=-\frac{1}{n}$ when $n\rightarrow \infty$ will converge to $f(x)=0$, which is not in either of them.
I still have no idea as for $C,D$ being closed or not, and which of the subgroups is open.

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: Consider functions with $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks! I can see how this helps with groups being open / not open. But I'm still now sure about C,D being closed or not

Comment: if $y_n \to y$ and for all $n, y_n \le 1$. Is it possible that $y > 1$?

Comment: No, but I can't see how it helps

Comment: Let $f_n \to f$ with $f_n \in C$ for all $n$. What can you prove about $f$?

Comment: So I say all the limit points of C (/D) are defined by a sequense of $f_n$, and prove that those limit points are in C (/D)?

Comment: In this case $C[-1,1]$ is first-countable, so identifying limit points by sequences is sufficient. But it is not necessary for this argument. I just used sequences as an example to get you thinking about it. You could use more general limits, or turn the argument around and show that every function not in $C$ (resp. $D$) has a neighborhood that misses it.

Comment: great! thank you!